# My access VBA code for creating excel files with data connections works on the first file then always fails at random points

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, connection

I have written some code in Access to copy an excel template file, perform some refresh and simple transsformations on the copy, save, and then move to the next file.  Initially i could create multiple files by looping through a list but kept getting odd errors on random lines during subsequent iterations.  I've avoided Active anything as that seems to be problematic, but still the code fails on the second iteration.  Mostly its on the Connection.Refresh but sometimes it is other lines such as "Method Rows of object Global failed".  I'm fairly experienced on this.  I also tried setting all my vba excel objects to nothing at the end of each loop but that didnt help.  Code below.  Any ideas gratefully recieved:

```
Sub CreateFilesIndividual()

     Dim mw As Variant
     Dim ccount As Integer
     Dim rs As Recordset
     Dim i As Integer

     Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT CM1920 as CM from Comm1920 order by rscount desc", dbOpenSnapshot)
     If rs.RecordCount = 0 Then
         MsgBox "No Commissioners Codes available - exiting"
         Exit Sub
     End If

     For i = 1 To rs.RecordCount
         CreateFile rs("CM")
     Next

End Sub

Sub CreateFile(commCode)

     Dim templateloc As String
     Dim fileloc As String
     Dim Xl As Excel.Application
     Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
     Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
     Dim ws2 As Excel.Worksheet
     Dim ws3 As Excel.Worksheet
     Dim ws4 As Excel.Worksheet

     templateloc = "\\gstt.local\Users\01\MWaring\Documents\Bespoke Report Requests\Contracts automation\Proposal template CCGs 2021 v2.6.xlsm"
     fileloc = "\\gstt.local\Users\01\MWaring\Documents\Bespoke Report Requests\Contracts automation\test\Proposal CCGs 1920 v2.6 " & commCode & ".xlsm"

     FileCopy templateloc, fileloc
    '
     Set Xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
     Set wb = Xl.Workbooks.Open(fileloc)
     Set ws = wb.Sheets("Commissioner Summary")
     ws.Unprotect
     ws.Cells(2, 4) = commCode.Value
     Debug.Print ws.Cells(2, 4).Value & " - " & commCode.Value
     wb.Connections("Update1").Refresh
     Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("Contract Category Detail")
     ws2.Range("A:AM").Copy

     Set ws3 = wb.Sheets("CC detail")
     ws3.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
     ws3.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
     ws3.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
    xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    ws3.Range("AG3").FormulaR1C1 = "=ROUND(RC[-2]+RC[-1],0)"
    Dim myrange As Integer
    myrange = ws3.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ws3.Range("AG3:AG" & myrange).FillDown

    ws3.Range("AL3").FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-5]*RC34"
    ws3.Range("AL3:AL" & myrange).FillDown
    ws3.Range("A:AM").Copy

    Set ws4 = wb.Sheets("Contract_Category_detail")
    ws4.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
    ws4.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    ws4.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
    xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    ws2.Delete
    ws3.Delete

    wb.Save
    wb.Close

    'Clean up
    Xl.Quit
    Set ws = Nothing
    Set ws2 = Nothing
    Set ws3 = Nothing
    Set ws4 = Nothing
    Set wb = Nothing
    Set Xl = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I had a strange error (probably the same) when I performed lots of copy-paste operations with Excel from Access. Than I created a function ClearClipboard() which I call after all such operation. Here it is:

```vb
Private Declare Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
Private Declare Function EmptyClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long

Public Function ClearClipboard()
    OpenClipboard (0&)
    EmptyClipboard
    CloseClipboard
End Function
```

Try it. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just curious...when was the last time you rebooted your machine.  It's been a while since I've done anything major with VBA, but as I recall, sometimes I would get weird, and inexplicable, errors just like you described.  I traced the errors to control breaks; when you stop VBA code by simultaneously hitting Ctrl+Break keys.  After a while, the control breaks would build up, and it would cause all kinds of bizarre issues.  Simply rebooting the machine fixed everything.  Try that and feed back with your findings.

Comment: Hi Ash  Thanks for the comment.  I had been rebooting to try to fix the issue - it does remove locks on files sometimes,  which makes me think that perhaps it is a memory leak or something.  But i religiously set my automation objects to Nothing even if an error occurs.  Rebooting doesnt seem to help here though, its always the second iteration which fails.  I'll keep trying and post anything if i can find a fix.